# How can I send a text to a bluetooth bracelet?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to send a text to this device: 
http://www.techdigest.tv/assets_c/2009/02/bluetooth-bracelet-thumb-480x318-78581.png
from an android phone. I have it paired with the phone. In my code, I just showed its mac address and confirmed that it's paired then I stopped. I don't know what to do next! but I gotta do it.
Please help.......

Comment: You've linked to a picture. Could you at least link to some more specs of the device?

Answer (score 0):

something like this ? http://ffejery.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/custom-alerts-on-a-bluetooth-enabled-bracelet/, sorry I don't have the android SDK to adapt the python script bu this is definitly worth a look